# nodata pixels in classified raster

Tags: r, classification

first of all: this is the first research I'm doing using remote sensing data and therefore this is a very basic question:
I'm doing a research regarding the classification of grasland use in the year 2021 using Sentinel2 data. The aim of the project is to produce a raster which classifies the research area into 3 categories (moving, grazing and natural graslands).
The first step is to classify the area into grasland and no-grasland doing a supervised classification (with rpart in R). The training samples are classified using the S2 GlobalLandCover data (https://s2glc.cbk.waw.pl/extension).
There are only a few images for the vegetation periode 2021 which have cloud coverage < 20% (unfortunately mainly in the main mowing season around june/july).
Therefore the timeseries for the sample points (or some NDVI scenes) contain NA-values. Even if I omit all the samples where NA-values occure, the final raster product has nodata pixels for the areas where there was cloud coverage (in any image).
I don't want to impute the missing values, because of the risk that a mowing event (decrease of the NDVI value) is lost.
Is there another supervised classification algorithm which is able to ignore this NA's or any other way to work around this and somehow compute these nodata pixels?